# Google Classroom 403: "The caller does not have permission" error

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-classroom

I am trying to register the user with Google Classroom Pub/Sub notifications, but I keep getting a `403: "The caller does not have permission"` error. I have set up the Pub/Sub topic correctly in the Google Admin Console with the ID `"gclassroom"`, so my topic ID is along the lines of `"projects/myappid-12345/topics/gclassroom"`. I have also set up `classroom-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com` as a Pub/Sub publisher under this topic.

My code:

```
private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeClassroomCoursesReadonly, kGTLRAuthScopeClassroomCourseworkMeReadonly, kGTLRAuthScopeClassroomPushNotifications, kGTLRAuthScopeClassroomRostersReadonly]
private let service = GTLRClassroomService()

@IBAction func signInButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    // Configure Google Sign-in.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = scopes

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {

    self.service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()

    let feed = GTLRClassroom_Feed()
    feed.feedType = kGTLRClassroom_Feed_FeedType_DomainRosterChanges

    let topic = GTLRClassroom_CloudPubsubTopic()
    topic.topicName = "projects/myappid-12345/topics/gclassroom"

    let registration = GTLRClassroom_Registration()
    registration.cloudPubsubTopic = topic
    registration.feed = feed
    let query = GTLRClassroomQuery_RegistrationsCreate.query(withObject: registration)
    service.executeQuery(query,
                         delegate: self,
                         didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
}
```

When I run it, I am able to sign in with my Google Classroom account, but it then immediately throws this error:

```
["GTLRStructuredError": GTLRErrorObject 0x604000a566b0: {errors:[1] message:"The caller does not have permission" code:403 status:"PERMISSION_DENIED"}, "NSLocalizedDescription": The caller does not have permission]
```

What can I do to fix this code and let the user register? Thanks.

Comment: Is this the [error](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/errors#top_of_page) you are getting? If so, it means that the user trying to access the classroom doesn't have a permission. Recommendation is to `direct the user to instructions on `[`enabling Classroom data access`](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6250906)`. Also see` [`ClassroomDisabled`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Access.Errors#classroomdisabled)`, as the user may be using the wrong account`.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to these! It looks like it's my school that is blocking access to the API.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I looked into it more, and I actually am able to log in with my school Google Classroom account and download coursework; however, I still cannot register for Pub/Sub notifications. The error is still the same as the one above and it does not contain any of the messages shown in the link you sent me. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the pod you used to integrate Google Classroom

Comment: @isuru You can use the [GoogleAPIClientForREST](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAPIClientForREST) library. I was able to fetch assignments with no issues but stopped using Pub/Sub. I think my original issue had to do with using the wrong client ID in my app, although I can't say for sure because I ended up moving all the Google Classroom processing to the server side.

Comment: @wgramer03 Is there a way to pass image within my iOS app directly to Google Classroom app/web?

Comment: @isuru Just linking your question here for others to see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61884460/how-to-share-image-to-google-classroom-in-ios