# How to share image to Google Classroom in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api-client, google-classroom

I want share an image within my application to Google Classroom.

```
NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_contentImageView.image);
NSString* base64Str = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://classroom.google.com/share?img=%@",base64Str]] options:@{@"img": base64Str} completionHandler:nil];
```

Tried with above code to share image directly to their URL by encoding image data but no result. Couldn't find proper documentation.So how to share image to Google Classroom?

Comment: I just tried it on the web with an image data URL and it didn't work. I think you need to pass a URL pointing to an actual online image, so you'll have to upload the image first. Do you happen to be using Firebase?

Comment: @wgramer03 Yes I tried it that way. I think that is the only way.